# Quotient by compact topological group has closed projection

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, quotient-spaces

Let $X$ a topological space and $G$ a compact topological group, why is the quotient map
$$\pi \colon X \to X/G$$
closed?

---

For every closed subset $C$ of $X$
$$\pi^{-1}(\pi(C)) = \bigcup_{g \in G}g\cdot C,$$
so we have to show that this subset is closed, but it is not evident to me the reason why this eventually infinite union should be closed.

**Context:** I’m trying to prove that $\pi$ is a proper map.

Edit: the suggested question is about the multiplication map $\mu \colon G \times X \to X$. This map is closed, unfortunately I can’t see why this should help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [action of a compact group is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2531861/action-of-a-compact-group-is-closed)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez thank you! It is clear to me now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mu \colon G \times X \to X$ the action map, this map is closed because $G$ is compact.

Let $C$ be a closed subset of $X$, then $G \times C$ is a closed subset of $G \times X$ so is $\mu(G \times C) \subset X$. We have:
$$\mu(G \times C)=G \cdot C=\bigcup_{g\in G}g\cdot C=\pi^{-1}(\pi(C)),$$

so $\pi(C)$ is a closed subset of $X/G$.